# what is mean of 'apply from' in gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

When I run this gradle task

```
-Pcons=value anyTask --stacktrace --info --debug
```

It executes the `build.gradle` file. And this file contains the line

```
apply from:"another.gradle"
```

In this scenario when I run `anyTask`, does all the code in `another.gradle` work? Or is it just accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way how script plugins are apllied. This is how it's described in the [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins).

> Script plugins are additional build scripts that further configure the build and usually implement a declarative approach to manipulating the build. They are typically used within a build although they can be externalized and accessed from a remote location.

And

> Script plugins are automatically resolved and can be applied from a script on the local filesystem or at a remote location. Filesystem locations are relative to the project directory, while remote script locations are specified with an HTTP URL. Multiple script plugins (of either form) can be applied to a given target.

Comment: In this scenario when I run `anyTask`, does all the code in `another.gradle` work? Or are they **just** accessible?